# SFTP hangs after correct authentication, SSH works

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, sftp

I got a raspberry pi 4, I enabled SSH, and I want to connect to it via SFTP from windows (also tried from android phone and same issue).
In the gif the top window is connected using SSH and i run a tail on the logs file.

In the second window I run sftp and try to login with an incorrect password the first time, and I enter the correct one on the second try. The console just remains hanging. [Gif is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B43F2.gif)

`tail auth.log -f`

```
Jan  8 19:42:28 raspberrypi sshd[10184]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.2.165  user=pi
Jan  8 19:42:30 raspberrypi sshd[10184]: Failed password for pi from 192.168.2.165 port 62685 ssh2
Jan  8 19:42:33 raspberrypi sshd[10184]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.2.165 port 62685 ssh2
Jan  8 19:42:33 raspberrypi sshd[10184]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jan  8 19:42:33 raspberrypi systemd-logind[407]: New session c100 of user pi.
Jan  8 19:42:33 raspberrypi sftp-server[10217]: session opened for local user pi from [192.168.2.165]
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi sshd[10215]: Received disconnect from 192.168.2.165 port 62685:11: disconnected by user
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi sshd[10215]: Disconnected from user pi 192.168.2.165 port 62685
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi sftp-server[10217]: session closed for local user pi from [192.168.2.165]
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi sshd[10184]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi systemd-logind[407]: Session c100 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jan  8 19:42:38 raspberrypi systemd-logind[407]: Removed session c100.
```

[image: WinScp]

It appears that the connection is successful but something gets stuck along the way.

Running SFTP command **from inside raspberry pi** seems to work. But connecting with sftp to localhost is not really useful :)

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/ssh $ sftp pi@localhost
pi@localhost's password:
Connected to pi@localhost.
sftp> exit
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/ssh $
```

Running `sftp -vvv pi@192.168.2.196` will give the folloing output

```
....
pi@192.168.2.196's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.2.196 ([192.168.2.196]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768

GETS STUCK HERE
```

## Update

It appears to be either a network problem or a driver problem.
I connected the Raspberry Pi to the 2.4Ghz instead of the 5Ghz (PC remained on 5ghz) and **IT WORKED**.

I also took a `tcpdump -i wlan0 port 22 -n -Q inout` when it's working and when it is not, you can see it below (removed timestamps for easy diffs).

```
WORKING:

IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 1494555936:1494556020, ack 4046582101, win 512, length 84
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 84, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 1:29, ack 84, win 272, length 28
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 84:196, ack 29, win 512, length 112
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 196, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 29:529, ack 196, win 272, length 500
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [.], ack 529, win 510, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 529:573, ack 196, win 272, length 44
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 196:248, ack 573, win 510, length 52
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 248, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 248:292, ack 645, win 510, length 44
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 645:833, ack 292, win 272, length 188
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 292:336, ack 833, win 509, length 44
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 336:380, ack 833, win 509, length 44
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 380, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 833:909, ack 380, win 272, length 76
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [.], ack 909, win 509, length 0
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 380:416, ack 909, win 509, length 36
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 909:1033, ack 416, win 272, length 124
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 416:452, ack 1033, win 508, length 36
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 452:512, ack 1033, win 508, length 60
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 512, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [R.], seq 512, ack 1033, win 0, length 0

NOT WORKING:

IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 565297912:565297996, ack 2156825212, win 512, length 84
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 84, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 1:29, ack 84, win 272, length 28
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 84:196, ack 29, win 512, length 112
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 196, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 29:529, ack 196, win 272, length 500
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [.], ack 529, win 510, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 529:573, ack 196, win 272, length 44
IP 192.168.2.244.64793 > 192.168.2.196.22: Flags [P.], seq 196:248, ack 573, win 510, length 52
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [.], ack 248, win 272, length 0
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
IP 192.168.2.196.22 > 192.168.2.244.64793: Flags [P.], seq 573:645, ack 248, win 272, length 72
```

More details:

- OS: Raspbian 10 buster (latest, just updated it)

Comment: After the authentication the sftp command starts the sftp server on the server side. I would assume that something goes wrong when starting the sftp server. Check the ssh logs on the server side.

Comment: Please do note post animated gifs. Instead post the console output in your question and format as code.

Comment: @DavidPostill removed gif, but kept it as a link, it's relevant to show the corelation between the second window I think.

Comment: It's good you posted the output of `sftp -v` where it fails. For comparison `sftp` that succeeds should also be posted with `-v`. Or maybe even `-vv` for both.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski oh didn't knew you could do that, updated with `sftp -vvv`

Comment: @Robert, well the only logs I could find is the `/var/log/auth.log` but check the update I posted a tcpdump.